# Handle Integer in DateSk

Tags: sql-server

I have a DateSurragate Key column and i need a end of week column  for that  DateSurragate Key ,,, 
I created a user defined function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn (@dt date)
RETURNS date
AS 

BEGIN
    DECLARE @result date
    select @result = dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, @dt), 4)
       RETURN @result;
END;
GO
```

This function  works with date but when values like -1 and -2 are passed it gives NULL
PLEASE let me know how i can change this function so that it can handle integer values I am new to tsql

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is not wrong(to determine whether input value is valid date or not?)

USE `ISDATE(expression)` function:
EX:

```
   DECLARE @datestring varchar(8)  
    SET @datestring = '12/21/98'  
    SELECT ISDATE(@datestring)
```

Similarly check for your input parameter within Function in the beginning.
Raise error or change the flow in func if ISDATE() return 0 in your case.